# How to log all queries to Outlook Web Access (msexchange 2010)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

We have MS Exchange 2010 with Outlook Web Access.

IIS logging is enable. It works for everything like :

- `/RPC/*`
- `/autodiscover/*`
- ...

And it works also for :

- `/OWA`
- `/owa/auth/logon.aspx`
- `/owa/ev.owa`

But it doesn't work for queries like :

- `/owa/?ae=Folders*`
- `/owa/?ae=Item*`

How can I fix the configuration to log all queries ?

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the logged requests and the not logged ones is the query string which is present only on the later (the part after the '?' charcater).

You have to enable printing the query string on IIS'l log, here you can find more information on how to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918561/does-iis7-log-request-query-string-by-default

Comment: Query string is already checked :/

Comment: Do you see it in your log file? Note that the query string gets printed to another field without the '?'